# Does not have storage.objects.get access

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I can not solve GCS bucket permission issue when submitting job to Dataproc.

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Created a project
2. Created a bucket `xmitya-test`
3. Created a cluster:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create cascade --bucket=xmitya-test \
    --master-boot-disk-size=80G --master-boot-disk-type=pd-standard \
    --num-master-local-ssds=0 --num-masters=1 \
    --num-workers=2 --num-worker-local-ssds=0 \
    --worker-boot-disk-size=80G --worker-boot-disk-type=pd-standard \
    --master-machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
    --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-2 \
    --zone=us-west1-a --image-version=1.3 \
    --properties 'hadoop-env:HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${HADOOP_CLASSPATH}:/etc/tez/conf:/usr/lib/tez/*:/usr/lib/tez/lib/*'
```

4. Uploaded job jar: `/apps/wordcount.jar` and library `/apps/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar`
5. Then submit a job with jar in classpath:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster=cascade \
    --jar=gs:/apps/wordcount.jar \
    --jars=gs://apps/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar --bucket=xmitya-test \
    -- gs:/input/url+page.200.txt gs:/output/wc.out local
```

Then I'm getting forbidden error accessing the library file:

```
java.io.IOException: Error accessing: bucket: apps, object: lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.wrapException(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1957)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1983)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getItemInfo(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1870)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1156)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1058)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2344)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.copyToLocalFile(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2320)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.util.HadoopUtil.download(HadoopUtil.java:70)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.AbstractJobHandler.downloadResources(AbstractJobHandler.java:448)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.AbstractJobHandler$StartDriver.call(AbstractJobHandler.java:579)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.AbstractJobHandler$StartDriver.call(AbstractJobHandler.java:568)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "714526773712-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to apps/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "714526773712-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to apps/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar."
}
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:401)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1097)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:499)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1978)
    ... 23 more
```

Tried set read permission from browser to `714526773712-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` user and set public permissions to all files: `gsutil defacl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://xmitya-test` and `gsutil acl ch -d allUsers:R gs://xmitya-test/**` - no effect.

What could be the reason?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about access to `apps`, `input` and `output` buckets, that you specified in parameters of job submission command:

> gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster=cascade --jar=**gs:/apps**/wordcount.jar --jars=**gs://apps**/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar --bucket=xmitya-test **gs:/input**/url+page.200.txt **gs:/output**/wc.out local

To fix this issue you need to grant access to these buckets or if these are folders inside `xmitya-test` bucket then you need to specify it explicitly in the path: `gs://xmitya-test/apps/wordcount.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to grant access? Whatever I do, I get the same error. I granted view and create access to bucket for `714526773712-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, to this object but still 403 forbidden.

Comment: You need to grant access to `xmitya-test` bucket (what seems you already have done) and change job submission command to `gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster=cascade --jar=gs://xmitya-test/apps/wordcount.jar --jars=gs://xmitya-test/apps/lib/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar --bucket=xmitya-test gs://xmitya-test/input/url+page.200.txt gs://xmitya-test/output/wc.out local`